# How to use specific members of a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, clang

I am trying to use the directive `using namespace NS` on a specific member but the compiler doesn't seems to understand so.

This is a very simple sample of code :

```
namespace NS{
    int a;
    int b;
}
using namespace NS::a;
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Clang compiler returns **error: expected namespace name at** *using namespace NS::a;*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is not namespace. So you can just pull contents of namespace in global namespace with `using namespace NS`, or pull only `a` in global namespace with `using NS::a`.

Answer (score 0):

`using namespace NS` means that `NS` is a namespace and you want to have direct access to its scope. So instead of `NS::a` you can write `a` directly.

While

`using namespace NS::a` means that `NS` is a namespace including another namespace `a` and you want to have access to variables defined in scope of namespace `a` !!!